# Как поставить vue-owl-carousel в nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Сделал все по инструкции

```
import Carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'
сomponents: { Carousel }
```

В итоге ошибка компонент не найден

Нигде не могу найти нужную информацию, как это реализовать?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'

export default {
    components: { carousel },
}
```

Попробуй carousel c маленькой буквы написать как в [инструкции](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel)

Comment: Опечатался в примере) Я и делал с маленькой буквы и не работает

Comment: ты его точно установил? проверь package.json

Comment: Ну конечно. Просто в nuxt.js свои приколы с установкой пакетами вот и не понимаю как правильно поставить

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.

```
<carousel v-if="isNuxtReady">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4">
</carousel>

<script>
  const carousel = () => window && window !== undefined ? import("vue-owl-carousel") : null;
  export default {
    components: { carousel },
    data() {
      return {
        isNuxtReady: false,
     }
    },
    mounted() {
      const vm = this;
      if (process.browser) {
        window.onNuxtReady(app => {
          console.log("Nuxt ready!");
          vm.isNuxtReady = true;
        });
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```